# Assign CallCenter Users via Apex

Tags: apex, call-center

Can we assign Users to a CallCenter via Apex? There's a standard object call CallCenterRoutingMap in the Object reference guide which looks like does the trick. But I don't see the object, though my API version is 53.0. Any Idea?

Comment: Have you configured a Call Centre in Salesforce?  Maybe this object only shows up when you configure a Call Centre.

Comment: Yes, it's already configured. I can see the CallCenter Object, but not CallCenterRoutingMap

Comment: I am facing the same confusion. Were you able to resolve this issue ? [@Mudiyanse](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/18794/l-mudiyanse)